# ConnectionError: Unknown service '//blp/refdata' when running bquery = blp.BlpQuery().start()

Tags: python, bloomberg

When running the script:

```
from blp import blp
bquery = blp.BlpQuery().start()
```

I'm getting error:

> ConnectionError: Unknown service '//blp/refdata' when running bquery = blp.BlpQuery().start()

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

From Bloomberg - this fixed it:Start Menu, then navigate to the Bloomberg folder, and then click "Stop API Process."

When the window pops up, please follow the on-screen prompts to close out of all Microsoft Office programs.

Please go to your Start Menu > Bloomberg > API Environment Diagnostics. In the window that opens, please click "Start." and then "Repair"

Comment: That thing solves a lot of problems.